# Need help in positioning divs when minimizing browser

Tags: css, html

In my html page, I have 3 divs. Their positioning are:

```
.rightPanel1 {
   position: absolute;
   right: 3%;
   top: 15%;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: teal;
   border-width: 0.5px;
   padding-left: 0.5%;
   padding-right: 0.5%;
   padding-bottom: 0.5%;
   padding-top: 0.5%;
}
.rightPanel2 {
   position: absolute;
   right: 3%;
} pithigoooo top: 37%;
        padding-left: 0.5%;
    padding-right: 0.5%;
    padding-bottom: 0.5%;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: teal;
    border-width: 0.5px;
        padding-top : 0.5%;
    padding-left: 0.5%;
    padding-top: 0.5%;
      }
.body {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3%;
    right: 25%;
    top: 15%;
   }
```

Now when browser is minimized, all divs tend to overlap each other. No scrollbar appears in the browser as what usually happens in other websites. What should I do to achieve it?

Comment: you've everything absolute, make body position: relative; or don't give any position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should fix your body height and width.

ex:

```
.body {   
height: 900px;
width: 1000px;
 }
```

Comment: "=" i have never seen this in css.